# How to call methods from different classes in ruby

Tags: ruby

Hi I am new to ruby and have recently started learning the same.I have written below ruby program which runs perfectly.

But this all program is written  in a single file.I want to place each class in a different file and  use one more file to execute all.ie like we do in java.[One main method to start the program] How can i run  this program like this.

When i tried keeping each class in individual file and tried executing the same it started giving errors like method not found.

```
class Vehical
  attr_accessor :odometer      
  attr_accessor :gas_used      
  def accelrate
    puts " Floor It"
  end

  def sound_horn
    puts "Beep! Beep!"
  end

  def steer
    puts "Turn front 2 wheels"
  end

  def mileage
    @odometer /@gas_used
  end
end

class Truck < Vehical
end

class Motercycle < Vehical
end


class Car < Vehical
end    

truck = Truck.new    
truck.steer
car = Car.new
car.odometer = 11432
car.gas_used = 366
puts "Lifetime MPG:"
puts car.mileage
```

Comment: "it started giving errors like method not found." – Don't tell us what the errors were "like". Tell us what the errors *are*. There should be a file name and line number in the error message, a stack trace telling you exactly *what* went wrong, in *which method* in *which line* of *which file* it went wrong, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are few options:

1. Use `require_relative` to load those files into main file.

   ```
   require_relative "vehical"
   require_relative "truck"
   require_relative "motor_cycle"
   require_relative "car"
   ```
2. Use `$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)` in main file to add its location to Ruby Load path, and use `require "dependent-file-name-without-extension"` in main file.

   ```
   $:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
   require "vehical"
   require "truck"
   require "motor_cycle"
   require "car"
   ```
3. Use `-I <folder>` when running the program. Example: `ruby -I . main.rb`

   > -Idirectory     specify $LOAD_PATH directory (may be used more than once)